# DataSource Deployment Tool

Tags: java, deployment, datasource

Reading [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) on `DataSource` the text keeps saying thins like:

> **The system administrator would typically use a deployment tool**, so the
>   code fragments shown in this section are the code that a **deployment
>   tool** would execute.

I have no idea on the deployment tools available, could anyone point me out the top options?

I am using Tomcat for my web application.

Comment: I think they are referring to java deployment tools such as jenkins, go, chef, ansible etc., Rather hardcoding datasource properties, isolate and configure in a config file. During deployments, it is easy to layer the configs across different environments. Each environment will have different datasource configurations (url, credentials may vary). With the help of few orchestration tools such as ansible and puppet, it is possible to generate config files pertaining to each environment. These tools are frequently used by system administrators to install, configure, manage and monitor systems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author is talking about java deployment tools. Below are the few deployment tools I'm aware of,

1. [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
2. [go](https://www.gocd.io/)
3. [bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)

These java deployment tools typically need configuration/orchestration tools to streamline the configuring and maintaining applications and the hosts. Below are some tools which does this :

1. [ansible](https://ansible.com)
2. [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/)

For dependency, build and project management, [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [gradle](https://gradle.org/) are widely used.

To generate config files for different environments,[xslt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/intro.html) transformation language can also be used.

I might have missed many deployment tools, but these are more popular in java realm.

With the help of these tools, a system administrator can manage the deployments without having any working knowledge of programming languages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jenkins and Bamboo have the same link, is this right?

Comment: Thanks, have changed now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When a web-app has to run in the J2EE environment, it typically is done using a server like Tomcat (as you are right now doing in your application).

Now, apart from just placing files in a directory, a web-app requires a number of other steps to be done, before you can access all the intended functionality. For more on what deployment is and how to assemble your files, refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6087/dgdeploy.html)

That said, J2EE evolution and the emergence of many web-servers has over the years resulted in simplifying the deployment using batch files for example or APIs. These are what your article is referring as deployment tools. For Tomcat specifically, the detail can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)

Hope this helps you with the bigger picture of J2EE application management